# C++ compiling project with shared object (libtensorflow_cc.so) failed

Tags: c++, tensorflow

at the moment I'm facing some problems compiling (and running) a (huge) own project with support of Tensorflow. On my own system (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) everything works fine. Same procedure on a cluster leads to a compile error and I'm not able to find a solution yet.

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code**: YES
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: CentOS 7.4.1708
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: source (using the git repo)
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: 1.9
- **Python version**: 2.7.15
- **Bazel version (if compiling from source)**: 0.16
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: 7.30
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: not used
- **GPU model and memory**: Tesla K20m
- **Exact command to reproduce**:

  1. Cloned tensorflow repo from github
  2. Configure Bazel *(./configure in tensorflow repo)*
  3. Built libtensorflow_cc.so with bazel *(worked fine!!!)*
  4. Downloaded dependencies with delivered script **tensorflow/contrib/makefile/download_dependencies.sh**
     (tried installing protobuf & eigen manually, too)!
  5. Installed **protobuf** with ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install
  6. Installed Eigen from downloaded dependencies
  7. Copied libraries, headers and includes into own project:

     ```
     $ cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so ../tf_project/lib/
     $ cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so ../tf_project/lib/
     $ cp /tmp/proto/lib/libprotobuf.a ../tf_project/lib/
     $ mkdir -p ../tf_project/include/tensorflow
     $ cp -r bazel-genfiles/ * ../tf_project/include/
     $ cp -r tensorflow/cc ../tf_project/include/tensorflow
     $ cp -r tensorflow/core ../tf_project/include/tensorflow
     $ cp -r third_party ../tf_project/include
     $ cp -r /tmp/proto/include/ * ../tf_project/include
     $ cp -r /tmp/eigen/include/eigen3/ * ../tf_project/include
     ```

**Remark:** On **my own** system it works this way for weeks now. I can use tensorflow in my own project with an exported model trained with keras inside a python project. I make predictions using client_sessions and many other functions of the tensorflow framework and it works properly.

**Problem:** At the cluster I can compile tensorflow as dynamic library, install protobuf and eigen. 
When I try to compile my project (similar process regarding my own system) without significant changes it doesn't work and stops with following error message:

```
.../tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:12:2: error: #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
 #error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
  ^~~~~
.../include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:13:2: error: #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers. Please update
 #error incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update
  ^~~~~
.../include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:14:2: error: #error your headers.
 #error your headers.
  ^~~~~
.../include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.pb.h:27:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So, clearly this should be the issue:

This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is incompatible with your Protocol Buffer headers.  Please update your headers.

and

**fatal error:** google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h: No such file or directory

Tried solutions:

1. I tried different versions of **protobuf** but there was an error every single try.
2. I tried installing **protobuf** and **eigen** manually (without the download_dependencies.sh script)

I'm wondering because my own installation following exact the same steps works properly. Maybe there is an issue with one of the components unless I tried different versions to make sure that these aren't "new" issues.

Can someone help me solving this error that I can compile and run this project at the other machine?

Looking forward to get helpful solutions :) Thank you very much for the support!

Best regards from Germany!

Comment: I may be even if you have installed the protobuf the system is getting it from another place. Check your `PATH` to see which protobuf it is taking.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Unfortunately there is just one installation of protobuf inside this system. That is which I installed following step 5!

Answer (score 1):

First, I checked on github, tensorflow r1.9 requires protobuf >=3.6.0. With download_dependencies.sh script, you always get protobuf 3.5.0, in which lack of inlined_string_field.h and some other headers.

Second, some errors that ask you to update protobuf version. I tried many versions of protobuf too. Only version 3.6.0 works well, rather than version 3.6.1 or older ones.

For these errors,

> error This file was generated by a newer version of protoc which is
>
> fatal error: google/protobuf/inlined_string_field.h: No such file or directory

It is a mismatch version problem. My solutions is that manually download protobuf 3.6.0 from
https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.6.0/protoc-3.6.0-linux-x86_64.zip

install it and `cp /usr/local/include/google to somewhere/tf/include`. It works quite well for me. I don't know if you tried version 3.6.0.

> download_dependencies.sh script would provide a mismatch version of
>   protobuf. See the issue I posted on github
>   https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22536

Also, I noticed your copied files are different from mine. I did in this way.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/tensorflow/include
sudo cp -r tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen/Eigen /usr/local/tensorflow/include/
sudo cp -r tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen/unsupported /usr/local/tensorflow/include/
sudo cp -r tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf/include/google /usr/local/tensorflow/include/
sudo cp tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/public/* /usr/local/tensorflow/include/
sudo cp -r bazel-genfiles/tensorflow /usr/local/tensorflow/include/
sudo cp -r tensorflow/cc /usr/local/tensorflow/include/tensorflow
sudo cp -r tensorflow/core /usr/local/tensorflow/include/tensorflow
sudo mkdir /usr/local/tensorflow/include/third_party
sudo cp -r third_party/eigen3 /usr/local/tensorflow/include/third_party/
sudo mkdir /usr/local/tensorflow/lib
sudo cp bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_*.so /usr/local/tensorflow/lib
```

Btw, I run build_all_linux.sh instead of download_dependencies.sh.

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for this! I also needed to copy across `sudo cp -r tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/absl /usr/local/tensorflow/include`

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem before, following is my solution:

I  successfully built `tensorflow-r1.8` with `bazel`. And I found `protoc` in following path is 3.5.0:

```
/home/zsb/.cache/bazel/_bazel_zsb/1372f28eb0671f692e7ac38330377d8c/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf_archive/protoc --version
```

but actually my system config is using `protoc` version `3.4.0`
I confirmed this by type `"protoc --version"` directly.

So finally I update system `protobuffer` version to `3.5.0` and this problem fixed.